# Is it possible to make this shorter?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm at a point where I want to try and make code more concise; is it possible to do that with the two lines (var textbox..., trays...)  I have below?

```
public void AddTrayToList(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        var textbox = (TextBox)sender;
        trays = TrayManager.AssignTrayToList(trays, textbox.Text);           
    }

}
```

Comment: Sure: `trays = TrayManager.AssignTrayToList(trays, ((TextBox)sender).Text);`.

Comment: Thanks, this was my first time asking a question and forgot that. Both the comment above and the answer below work very well and (although the concepts may be trivial for some) hopefully will help other new users such as myself improve their coding ability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful about making code shorter just to be more concise. More concise does not always mean more readable or easier to understand, and it definitely does not mean more performant. Here is a slight refactor to your method that makes things shorter *and* adds more type safety checks.

```cs
public void AddTrayToList(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //add using Windows.System at the top of your file.
    if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter && sender is TextBox textbox)
    {
        trays = TrayManager.AssignTrayToList(trays, textbox.Text);           
    }

}
```